# Typo3 strange https redirects

Tags: php, http, redirect, https, typo3

i have a really weird problem on a typo3 site.
The site currently runs on Typo3 4.6.6 (yeah i know we are in the process of upgrading it to 6.2 LTS)

In the backend we have 3 separate pages. The webspace where this site runs was currently upgraded to PHP 5.5. Nothing else has changed (as far as we know)

The problem is that on certain pages we get redirected to a https version of the same page, although the link is a http link.

See for instance here: http://www.phd-cell-signaling.at/home.html
If you open this it loads fine. But as soon as you click on a (http) link on the site, you get redirected to an https version hence the browser doesn't load all the stuff included via http (stylesheets for instance). But when you then delete the "s" from the address bar and hit enter you don't get redirected. And this is something i don't really understand.

And if that'd be a general issue shouldn't the other pages in the same typo3 environment also be affected? Or am i missing something here.

Since I'm not that familiar with typo3 it would be greatly appreciated if somebody could link me in the right direction where the problem could be.

We use realURL for example. But I checked the configuration i found and it doesn't appear to do anything that causes the redirect.
I also checked the typoscript configuration of all the pages in the backend with no success.

Are there any other plugins that might cause something like this?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you follow a link on the page you posted, then the webserver returns the statuscode 301 (moved permanently) with the new location for that page (which is the requested page with the HTTPS scheme).

When TYPO3 is properly configured for SSL usage for single pages (so a backend user can use "Choose protocol" selectbox in the backend), then it already renders affected links with the proper scheme.

Your problem described can have multiple reasons. Please check the following:

1. Inspect the .htaccess file in the root directory of the TYPO3 website for any scheme redirects
2. Check if the webserver itself has configured scheme redirects for that virtual host
3. Goto the TYPO3 extension manager and search for local installed HTTPS or SSL redirection extensions